# Vue.js: reporting progress for a heavy operation

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Is there any way how can I report progress to the user of a heavy javascript operation in Vue.js?

I have the next code:

```
<p>{{currentProgress}}</p>

...

data: function() {
    return {
        isLoading : false,
        currentProgress: "",
    }
},
created: function() {
    globalLoading.subscribeOnChange((receivedLoading, progress) => {
        console.log("----> ", receivedLoading, progress);
        this.isLoading = receivedLoading;
        this.currentProgress = progress;

        this.$forceUpdate();
    });
},
```

The method `globalLoading.subscribeOnChange` is called during a big and heavy operation done in javascript (namely generating a pdf with `jsPDF`). It takes around a minute and I'd like to give a progress response to the user.

However, during this, I do not see any updates for `currentProgress` variable, until the pdf generation ends. I do not even see the update in `Vue.js` console in Developer Tools (F12).

I call this operation heavy because it definitely loads the browser - it is even hard to open Developer Tools during this. But if I open it before the operation - I can see `console.log` outputs, so I know that this code is running.

`this.$forceUpdate()` does not help.

*update:*
An example of a heavy operation could be something like this:

```
 methods: {
            testClick: function() {
                globalLoading.start("test");
                for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                    console.log("!");
                    globalLoading.updateProgress(i);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        },
```

I know that if I use `setInterval` instead of a loop it will work, but I need the heavy operation to be finished as soon as possible - I do not want to split operation into chunks

Comment: Move the heavy operation to a webworker and report the progress on the main thread.

Comment: @Nit Now I feel really stupid. Of course, I need webworker, I had no idea js has functionality like that. I have written a one, and it seems to report, but unfortunately very seldom. If I click on the screen, the number in `<p>` get's updated. Any clues?

Comment: @Nit The number in DevTools in component `data` now grows correctly as expected

Comment: @Nit forget the last comment, my bad. I think it works. I was calling `postMessage` too often

Comment: @Nit Ok, this is still an issue. Unfortunately `web workers` do not work for me: they do not have any access to DOM, when `jsPDF` (the heavy operation I'm doing) requires access to `window`. The question is still open

Comment: There's [an issue on their Github](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/57) that outlines how to get it to work with webworkers, unfortunately it isn't merged into the library itself. As a sidenote, as your profile shows you're a C# guy, allow me to briefly explain the problem you're facing — JS is single threaded by default. This means that while your PDF is generating, Vue can't update itself either since it's waiting on the generator. So the solution is to either break up the generator into pieces or move it to a worker, if possible.

Comment: @Nit thanks. I've started to work with JS only recently, and this is the whole new world. I guess I will have to break down the logic. I found  a neat way of how to do it using yield, but it is still a bit too complex for such a simple task.I'll try it tomorrow. Anyway, thanks, you've been a great help